# Object doesn't support this method or property error

Tags: java, javascript, applet, java-native-interface

Hi I created a jni jar and i call the jar using applet in java script. I use the following applet tag to create a object to call jar functions through java script. when i call the function i got the following error **Object doesn't support this method or property.**

Here is my code.

```
document.write('<applet code="BiomAPI.Legend.class" width="0" height="0" archive="BiomAPI.jar" id="Obj"></applet>');

function GetTemplateAccurate (sUserID,iFingerID)
{
    document.getElementsByName("Enroll")[0].value = "";
    document.getElementsByName("Image")[0].value = "";
    var lsFeature = null;
    var lsImage = null;

    Obj.EnableLog(0);
    Obj.LocalFilePath("C:\\IMAGE\\");
    Obj.EnableEncryption(0);
    Obj.SaveImage(1);
    Obj.SessionID("abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde");
    Obj.GetFeatureAccrual(sUserID,iFingerID);
    lsFeature = Obj.Feature();  
    lsImage = Obj.StringImage();

    if (lsFeature != null && lsImage != null )
    {
        document.getElementsByName("Enroll")[0].value = lsFeature;
        document.getElementsByName("Image")[0].value = lsImage;
        alert("Scanner Working Properly");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Fingerprint not captured");
    }
}

function GetTemplate(sUserID,iFingerID)
{
    document.getElementsByName("Verify")[0].value = "";
    var lsFeature = null;

    Obj.EnableLog(0);
    Obj.LocalFilePath("C:\\IMAGE\\");
    Obj.EnableEncryption(0);
    Obj.SessionID("abcde");
    Obj.SaveImage(1);
    Obj.GetFeature(sUserID,iFingerID);
    lsFeature = Obj.Feature();  
    lsImage = Obj.StringImage();

    if (lsFeature != null)
    {
        document.getElementsByName("Verify")[0].value = lsFeature;
        alert("Scanner Working Properly");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Fingerprint not captured");
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like java code!

Comment: @NarendraPathai It's javascript code that accesses public data fields in an applet through the magic of reflection.

Answer (score 1):

as exception itself is describing:

> Object doesn't support this method or property error

the property or method you are trying to access with an object is not supported by that object. Please debug or see on error console the object throwing exception and find whether it support that property you are trying to access.